# WP Super Cache conflicts Contact Form 7

Tags: ajax, wordpress, caching, contact-form-7

2 popular Wordpress plugins, **Super Cache** and **Contact Form 7** - there are still some issues expected around `_nonce` AJAX calls.. How it is possible to make them work together smoothly? *Definitely, there are some situations you want to keep ALL your posts (pages) super-cached, and not to be served dinamically without caching while preserving and providing contact form functionality.*

When not checking the "Cache rebuild" in the settings, Super Cache will function:

- standard pages will NOT enforce a new cache file to be generated (e.g. it REALLY serves an (if) existing supercache file whithout triggering a new cache file to be generated
- pages with a `wpcf7-form` included WILL enforce/trigger the re-generation of supercache file while serving the initial on the request. I think that is the point when things go wrong.

**Question**: How to stop unwanted re-generation of pages with a `wpcf7-form` included? Based on [wpcf7 plugin homepage Docs](http://contactform7.com/docs/) by the author, my expectation is that the wpcf7 form has evolved and been developing to meet this ajax-call requirements such `_nonce` calls. Any idea **how to resolve** this?

- to be hard-coded (e.g. exclude _nonce call and/or URL parameter..) within `wpcf7 form`  (this is against WP standards) or
- settings in Super cache?
- any other idea, solution or alternatives?

In [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-forms-not-sending-with-super-cache-enabled?replies=10) wpcf7 author says:

> Contact Form 7 uses WP nonce as secret key. As nonce life is 24 hours by default, if cache clears less than 24 hours, the two plugins should work without problem, even if the page is cached.